Creating a Teams Group with Microsoft.Graph v5.57 or above
How do you create a Team Group based on the "Class" Template which has id of "educationClass"? I can create a Teams group without a Template okay, but with the following code, I get an error

Could not find member 'template@odata.bind' on object of type 'Team'. Path '['template@odata.bind']', line 1, position 290

Any help would be much appreciated.
           Dim oTeam As New Team With {
               .Template = New TeamsTemplate With {
                   .Id = "educationClass"
               },
               .MemberSettings = New TeamMemberSettings With {
                   .AllowCreatePrivateChannels = True,
                   .AllowCreateUpdateChannels = True
               },
               .MessagingSettings = New TeamMessagingSettings With {
                   .AllowUserEditMessages = True,
                   .AllowUserDeleteMessages = True
               },
               .FunSettings = New TeamFunSettings With {
                   .AllowGiphy = True,
                   .GiphyContentRating = GiphyRatingType.Strict
               }
           }


Please have a look into this document-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#example-5-create-a-team-from-a-group-with-multiple-channels-installed-apps-and-pinned-tabs

Thanks I can now create the team, and its Owners/Memebers etc But the Class Notes and Home Page are not provisioned. If manually go to Teams -> Files within Microsoft Teams it provisions the Class Notbook and Home Page in Onedrive and starts working. I have tried  "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteId}/drives/{driveId}/root/children" to force a provision and it only seems to work on the Class Notebook and does not provision the Home Page. Any idea how to emulate what Teams is doing? Or is there a correct method for provisioning this in the Microsoft Graph API?

Please post a new question and check the answer below for creating teams

I agree with @Sayali-MSFT, to create teams use the below code:
class Program
{
    private static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        string clientId = "ClientID";
        string clientSecret = "Secret";
        string tenantId = "TenantID";

        var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);

        var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential);

        var requestBody = new Team
        {
            Channels = new List<Channel>
            {
                new Channel
                {
                    DisplayName = "Class Announcements ",
                    IsFavoriteByDefault = true,
                },
                new Channel
                {
                    DisplayName = "Homework ️",
                    IsFavoriteByDefault = true,
                },
            },
            MemberSettings = new TeamMemberSettings
            {
                AllowCreateUpdateChannels = false,
                AllowDeleteChannels = false,
                AllowAddRemoveApps = false,
                AllowCreateUpdateRemoveTabs = false,
                AllowCreateUpdateRemoveConnectors = false,
            },
            InstalledApps = new List<TeamsAppInstallation>
            {
                new TeamsAppInstallation
                {
                    AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>
                    {
                        {
                            "teamsApp@odata.bind", "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/appCatalogs/teamsApps('com.microsoft.teamspace.tab.vsts')"
                        },
                    },
                },
                new TeamsAppInstallation
                {
                    AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>
                    {
                        {
                            "teamsApp@odata.bind", "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/appCatalogs/teamsApps('xxx')"
                        },
                    },
                },
            },
            AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                {
                    "template@odata.bind", "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teamsTemplates('standard')"
                },
                {
                    "group@odata.bind", "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups('xxx')"
                },
            },
        };

        try
        {
            var result = await graphClient.Teams.PostAsync(requestBody);
            Console.WriteLine($"Team created successfully");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error creating team: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
}


Make sure to grant one of these permissions Team.Create ,Directory.ReadWrite.All, Group.ReadWrite.All:

Reference:
Create team - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft
